# Find last element of array in JSON column type

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

The following is an example of data stored as data type `json` in Postgres 9.4.4:

```
[
  1479772800000,
  70.12
],
[
  1479859200000,
  70.83
],
[
  1480032000000,
  71.23
]
```

How can I select the last element of this array: `[1480032000000,71.23]`

```
 \d stocks
                                     Table "public.stocks"
      Column      |         Type         |                      Modifiers                      
------------------+----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
 id               | integer              | not null default nextval('stocks_id_seq'::regclass)
 ticker           | character varying(6) |  
 price_history    | json                 | 
Indexes:
    "stocks_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "ix_stocks_ticker" UNIQUE, btree (ticker)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the last element of a Postgres JSON array by doing (known to work in Postgres 9.5+):

```
select '...'::json->-1;
```

This uses the `->` operator. Negative integers count from the end.

For example:

```
select '[[1479772800000, 70.12], [1479859200000, 70.83], [1480032000000, 71.23]]'::json->-1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Postgres 9.5 would be preferable, like [@Simeon provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40825175/939860).

You could use [`json_array_length()` in Postgres 9.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) since negative indexes are not allowed for the [`->` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE).

```
SELECT j -> -1                       AS pg95
     , j -> json_array_length(j) - 1 AS pg94
FROM (SELECT '[[1479772800000, 70.12]
             , [1479859200000, 70.83]
             , [1480032000000, 71.23]]'::json) t(j);
```

`-1` because JSON array indexes are 0-based (unlike 1-based Postgres arrays).

Comment: too late I upgraded postgres versions!

Comment: @JZ.: That's the right move. Doesn't change the question, though.